# TypeError: 'Player' object is not callable Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, typeerror

Ok guys I have such problem. Django returns me Type Error for such view. It is meant to be a turns system for a game:

```
@login_required
def game_end_turn(request, id):
    game = Game.objects.get(id=id)
    player = Player.objects.get(parent=request.user)
    if player == game.turn_of_player:
        game.turn_of_player = game.next_player()
        game.save()
        return redirect('detail', id=game.id)
    else:
        return redirect('detail',id=game.id)
```

model:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    host = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    is_played = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    max_players = models.IntegerField(default=4)
    who_is_ready = models.ManyToManyField(Player, related_name="guys_ready", blank=True)
    who_is_playing = models.ManyToManyField(Player, related_name="guys_playing", blank=True)
    turn = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    turn_of_player = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='czyja_tura', blank=True, null=True)
```

... and it's methods:

```
  @property
    def how_many_players_playing(self):
        return self.who_is_playing.count()



     @property
        def players_playing(self):
            return list(self.who_is_playing.all())

 @property
    def next_player(self):
        x = self.players_playing.index(self.turn_of_player)
        nast= x+1
        if nast > self.how_many_players_playing:
            self.turn +=1
            self.save()
            return self.players_playing[0]
        else:
            return self.players_playing[x+1]
```

And it ends with such error:

TypeError: 'Player' object is not callable:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dottore/PycharmProjects/CRUDE/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/dottore/PycharmProjects/CRUDE/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/dottore/PycharmProjects/CRUDE/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/dottore/PycharmProjects/CRUDE/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/dottore/PycharmProjects/Nowa_gra/Nova_gra/game/views.py", line 139, in game_end_turn
    game.turn_of_player = game.next_player()

Exception Type: TypeError at /game/2=end_turn
Exception Value: 'Player' object is not callable
```

Why I can't to assign that Player? Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `next_player` is a `@property`, you obtain the value with `game.next_player`, if you use brackets, you *call* the `Player` object, but the object is *not* callable (unless you implemented a `__call__` method, but you did not, and it is probably better not to do that anyway).

You thus should rewrite the line to:

```
    game.turn_of_player = game.next_player  # no ()
```